# Empty http and https declarations in Content Security Policy

Tags: nginx, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm using nginx to set the CSP header.

I often see this in examples:

```
default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.foo.com;
```

I understand that `https://*.foo.com` allows loading from the `foo.com` domain.

But what is the meaning of the "empty" `http:` and `https:` declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means allow content from all sites on that protocol. For example:

1. https://example.com
2. https://www.example.com
3. https://www.google.com
4. http://www.google.com
5. http://evilhacker.com

That policy, as it currently stands, basically allows everything and is pretty pointless!

Comment: So you're saying the `https://*.foo.com` is pointless because anything on that scheme is allowed?

Comment: So I guess I should also remove `http:`, `data:`, `blob:` as they are also not specific enough.

Comment: Ideally. Though it can be useful for some use cases. For example `default-src: https: ‘unsafe-inline’ ‘unsafe-eval’ ; upgrade-insecure-requests` can be useful to force https as a start without blocking anything. Then work on a stricter policy. Or could add a stricter `script-src`, `style-src`...etc. but allow images and videos to fallback to `default-src`. Though preference is to have a strict `default-src` and then looser `image-src` in this case.